# Vim: Close a fold on a specific line

Tags: vim

I want to programatically close a fold in vim based on whether or not it matches a regular expression. I've defined a function in my vimrc to do so:

```
" Support python 2 and 3 
if has('python')
    command! -nargs=1 Python2or3 python <args>
elseif has('python3')
    command! -nargs=1 Python2or3 python3 <args>
else
    echo "Error: Requires Vim compiled with +python or +python3"
    finish
endif

" Define function
func! FoldCopyrightHeader()
Python2or3 << EOF
import re
import vim
# Look at the first 30 lines
header = '\n'.join(vim.current.buffer[0:30])
pattern = 'Copyright .* by .* THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE'
match = re.search(pattern, header, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
if match:
    # Find the line number of the block to fold 
    lineno = header[:match.start()].count('\n') 
    # Remember the current position
    row, col = vim.current.window.cursor
    # move cursor to the fold block
    vim.command('cal cursor({},{})'.format(lineno, 0))
    # close the fold
    vim.command('call feedkeys("zc")')  
    # move back to the original position
    vim.command('cal cursor({},{})'.format(row, col))
EOF
endfunc
```

The idea is to search for the pattern, if it exists, then move to where the pattern is, enter the key commands `zc` to close the fold, and then move back to your original position.

However, this doesn't quite work. If I call this function via `:call FoldCopyrightHeader()`, then it closes whatever fold the cursor is currently on, and does nothing else.

My guess is that the `feedkeys` command is asynchronous  `vim.command('call feedkeys("zc")')` and is happening before/after the move cursor commands get executed.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I solved it as I was typing the question.

Using `vim.command(':foldclose')` instead of `vim.command('call feedkeys("zc")')` seems to do the trick.